# jdbc type1 program error

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

There is no compile time error but runtime error is there. i have assigned the DSN by going to controlPanel->administrative tools->Data sources->Add button->select oracle in XE->finish-> DSN=oradsn id=system ->ok ->ok
   but it is not still running. please help me out

```
/**
* Program1.java
* This program Creates table student
* columns: SID, SNAME, MARKS
* driver: Type-1(JDBC-ODBC Bridge)
* Database: Oracle 11g
*/
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
class Program1{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        //Step-1: Load driver class
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
        //step-2: open connection
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:oradsn","system","tiger");
            System.out.println("connection is opened");
        //step-3: create statement object
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("statement object created");
        //prepare command
            String cmd="create table faculty(SID number(5) primarykey, SNAME varchar(10), MARKS number(5))";
        //step-4:execute command
            int i=stmt.executeUpdate(cmd);
        //step-5: print result
            System.out.println("Table is created");
        //step-6: close connection
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
            System.out.println("connection closed");
    }//main
}//Program1
```

Comment: 1) What is the runtime error? 2) which Java version are you using (JdbcOdbcDriver was removed in Java 8)? 3) why aren't you using the Oracle JDBC driver?

Comment: Jdbc--odbc bridge is no longer supported in nevest versions of Java, simply don't use it, use Oracle jdbc driver instead